# Data from database does not appear anymore in view page (codeigniter)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, cpanel

My website is currently live and I have populated the table. I see in my table from the database that it contains attendees but in my view page, it does not display the data.

The first pic shows the number of students who attended the event "hello pat email". It only shows one attendee then after refreshing the page of the first pic it resulted to the second pic. 
[image: pic1]
The second pic show the list of students who attended the event. 
[image]
The third pic shows in the table from the db that it has 3 attendees.
[image]

I don't know if it has something to do with the api of the mobile app or with the cpanel. I'm using cpanel, phpmyadmin, and codeigniter as my framework.

Comment: Insufficnt information for us to form any conclusions, theres no code or other references for us to work with.

Comment: And also none of the images are visible.